# Published wget command line to fetch a PGP key for a repository doesn't work in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wget

Trying to install SublimeText 3 on a new laptop.

Various sources (including the SublimeText site, and "itsfoss") suggest this as a way to get the PGP key for the PPA:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

On 16.04 Ubuntu, that `wget` command does indeed fetch the key. However, on a fresh 18.04 installation, that command gets an error:

> wget: invalid option -- '0'

What changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mis-entered the arguments - that's a capital O not a zero.

The command you **want to run** is this one:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

... whereas the one you entered is most likely this one:

```
wget -q0 - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```